# Google Plus Sign-in: how to catch authorization event?

Tags: javascript, client, google-plus

I am trying to implement Google Plus Sign-in and I have downloaded a sample javascript sign-in example from https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript.

No changes have been made to the code.
When I open the page in Firefox or Chrome and click on the sign-in button a popup with an authorization request is shown. I click the 'Accept' button, the popup gets dismissed, but nothing changes on the page (sign-in button is still there). Only refreshing the page afterwards shows that I have already signed in. Doesn't happen in IE though.

The chrome console gives me the following error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   `https://plusone.google.com/_/widget/render/signin`... from frame with
>   URL `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval`....  Domains,
>   protocols and ports must match.

As far as I can see, the browser is blocking unsafe calls (am I right?).

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Is there a way to attach an event listener to the google's sign-in code?

Is it possible to force the sign-in button to open the authorization page in the tab/window and not in a popup window (G+ sign-in does not seem to have redirect_url option)?